# MySQL date range SELECT + JOIN query using column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Tags: sql, mysql, database, datetime

I am using this query:

```
SELECT p.id, count(clicks.ip)
FROM `p`
LEFT JOIN c clicks ON p.id = clicks.pid
WHERE clicks.ip = '111.222.333.444'
```

To select clicks from table "c", that has "pid" = "p.id". The query seems to work fine, but now I want to use that query with date ranges. The "c" table has a column "time" that uses MySQL CURRENT_TIMESTAMP data type (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS). **How can I use my query with date range using that column?**

I want to be able to select count(clicks.ip) from a specific day, and also group the results by hour (but this is for a different query).

Comment: I'm surprised that query works since you're missing the GROUP BY clause on the aggregate....

Comment: @Leslie: MySQL [supports "hidden columns" in the GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html)

Comment: huh, we're running MySQL 5.1.11 and when I use the Query Tool from the MySQL Administrator I get an error that I have to have the GROUP BY.  I even checked it before I posted...huh, weird...

Comment: I am using MySQL 4.1.22, I understand I forgot to add the GROUP BY on the query of my question, and I am using it in my code, but the query doesn't fail if I don't use it (from phpmyadmin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
   SELECT p.id, 
          COUNT(clicks.ip)
     FROM `p`
LEFT JOIN c clicks ON clicks.pid = p.id 
                  AND clicks.ip = '111.222.333.444'
                  AND clicks.time BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                                      AND NOW()
```

I provided an example that will count clicks that occurred between this time yesterday (`DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)`) and today (`NOW()`).  Mind that BETWEEN is inclusive.